# MVC structure in coding

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have these requirements as follows

- user must log in with username and password
- user can add a menu after the login is successful.

I tried to implement my codes using model view controller

login class.

http://pastebin.com/znK9BYT3

menu class

http://pastebin.com/uxTB7M0Z

As this is my first attempt using MVC, I don't understand how can I integrate my views in my mainclass such that the addNewMenuUI will be displayed only after the login is successful.

mainclass

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    login loginModel = new login;
    loginview loginView = new loginview(); 
    loginController lc = new loginController(loginModel,loginView);

    menu menuModel = new menu();
    menuview menyView = new menuview();
    menuController mC = new menuController(menuModel,menuView);     
}
```

please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

which MVC-framework do you use? To me it looks like you are building everything from scratch. It is easiest to use an already existing framework like [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) or [Play](http://www.playframework.com/). The ability to have a user login is something that comes out of the box or is easy to implement. Then based on the authentication you can determine if the user can see the menu or not (is that what you want?).

Take a look at [this tutorial which explains how to create a login application using Spring-MVC in Java](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-application-using-spring-mvc-in-java/27113).

And [adding authentication in the Play framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/guide8) might also be of interest to you.

Good luck!